# Opening a matplotlib pyplot in a tkinter canvas - import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to embed a pyplot in a tkinter canvas. I am using python 2.7 on Windows.

I looked around for some example code and I found the following in the matplotlib documentation.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
# implement the default mpl key bindings
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler


from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t,s)


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def on_key_event(event):
    print('you pressed %s'%event.key)
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key_event)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if
# the window is closed with the window manager.
```

However running this code gives me the following error:

```
from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg
```

Does anyone know what the go is here? I've only found people asking about this on python 3 or on another OS.

Comment: @behzad.nouri what does that mean? This code is from the matplotlib website so I would be surprised if it was an error in the source code.

Comment: Your installation is not correct.  `_tkagg` is a c-extension that should have been built when you installed mpl. Best bet is to re-install.